# Capturing multiline string with regex and replacing it with itself, indented on every line

Tags: regex, bash, grep, sublimetext

#### Background

I have a large batch of markdown files that have code blocks marked off with three backticks and a language name (github style). Like so:

````
```ruby
def method_missing
  puts "Where's the method?" 
end
```
````

I'd like to change the way these are marked off, so that instead of using three backticks, code blocks are set of with indentation (stack overflow style), as follows:

```
    def method_missing
      puts "Where's the method?" 
    end
```

#### Problem

I'm doing a find-and-replace across multiple files in Sublime Text with this expression

````
(?s)```ruby(.*?)```
````

This effectively captures what I'd like, but I'm having trouble finding a good way to replace the capture group `$1` with an indented version of itself. At best, I can insert a soft tab before the entire capture group.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Alternatively: Is there a quick way to do this with a bash script using `grep`?

Comment: You can replace `\n` with `\n\t`

Comment: Quite sadly I don't think you're going to get this to work with regex alone. You might have to build a parser that can go through and change it. IF your comment blocks were always the same number of lines, it would be fine. But I'm betting some are more than 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `grep`, but you could do it using text manipulation utilities like `sed`.  For example, saying:

````
sed -n '/```ruby/,/```/{/```ruby/b;/```/b;s/^/    /p }' filename
````

would produce:

```
    def method_missing
      puts "Where's the method?" 
    end
```

for your sample input.

It captures lines between ```` ```ruby ```` and three backticks; adds 4 spaces in front of those lines; and prints those.

If you want a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character instead of those whitespaces, substitute `s/^/    /p` with `s/^/\t/p` in the expression above.

Comment: +1 Not sure if it's possible to make it print everything? But I guess you could do it in-place and then strip the '```' lines

Comment: @BroSlow The question didn't state it quite clearly, but I assumed that OP wanted to print only the lines _between_ the specified patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could get a one line to work, but might just be simpler to do it with a shell script

````
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^'```ruby' ]]; then
    indent=true
  elif [[ $line =~ ^'```' ]]; then
    indent=
  else
    [[ -n $indent ]] && echo -e "\t$line" || echo "$line"
  fi
done < file
````